# is there any difference between if(!$array) and if(empty($array))

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Is there a case where doing this?

```
if(!$array) {
//... do stuff
}
```

Would produce different results than this?

```
if(empty($array)){
//... do stuff
}
```

Comment: I had this doubt today, and even though it is a simple question, I thought I would contribute it in case somebody decided to search stack for it. Maybe the wording is not perfect, so feel free to edit!

Comment: `if( $array )` and `if( empty( $array ) )` **never** will return same value. Maybe with a `!` somewhere...

Comment: @fusion3k whops! Thanks! I wrote it right in my head, I swear :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Not exactly.

As I found out on the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), empty() is actually equivalent to `!isset($var) || $var == false`.

In other words, `if(!$array)` and `if(empty($array)` would return the same value unless the $array is not set, in which the first piece of code would return an Exception